# How to store data from huge json array in another array based on a condition javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a huge json array.Now I need to seggregate this array and form another json array.And the condition for that is it should have "dbstatus":-3 in my each json object

```
  data = [{"id":"122","dbstatus":-3},{"id":"123","dbstatus":"-6"},{"id":"414","dbstatus":-3}]
```

Now in my new array it should have only following

```
  data2=[{"id":"122","dbstatus":-3},{"id":"414","dbstatus":-3}]
```

How can we do this.can someone help

Comment: Please have a look at *array.filter()*, it can do exactly what you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter) :

```js
var data = [{"id":"122","dbstatus":-3},{"id":"123","dbstatus":"-6"},{"id":"414","dbstatus":-3}];

console.log(data.filter(e => e.dbstatus == -3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
data.filter(function(o) {return o.dbstatus == -3})
```